# Why would El Niño affect atmospheric CO2 measurements?

Tags: atmospheric-science, meteorology

Starting with this article in Gizmodo: 
[El Niño Has Pushed Our Planet Past a Major Climate Milestone](http://gizmodo.com/el-nino-has-pushed-our-planet-past-a-major-climate-mile-1781903594) and then to this commentary in Nature Climate Change [El Niño and a record CO2 rise](http://www.nature.com/nclimate/journal/vaop/ncurrent/full/nclimate3063.html) there seems to be some connection.

I'm pretty sure that El Niño does not directly *produce* CO2! Can someone help me understand the discussion of the relationship from a physics perspective? *Did El Niño affect the measured values of atmospheric CO2*? Did it result in CO2 redistribution, or aid CO2 production in some way? My understanding is that El Niño is an unusual change in temperature distribution and wind direction.

I'm *not looking for individual opinions or theories*, I'd like an explanation of the concepts presented in those two links, from a physics perspective. Thanks!

Images from NOAA via the Gizmodo article:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the author of the Gizmondo article you cited explains,

> [...] scientists believe that emissions spiked due to a combination of **warming and drying in the tropics, which can accelerate soil carbon decomposition, and large, drought-fueled fires**.

[Here](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2016/06/160613130700.htm) you can find an equivalent explanation:

> The atmospheric carbon dioxide concentration is rising year-on-year due to human emissions, but this year it is getting an extra boost due to the recent El Niño event - changes in the sea-surface temperature of the tropical Pacific Ocean. **This warms and dries tropical ecosystems, reducing their uptake of carbon, and exacerbating forest fires**. Since human emissions are now 25 per cent greater than in the last big El Niño in 1997/98, this all adds up to a record CO2 rise this year.

[Here](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-36521068) they give the same explanation and also explain how the influence of El Niño on the increase in CO$_2$ concentration was predicted using numerical models:

> [...] carbon dioxide levels have seen a surge in recent months as a result of the El Niño climate phenomenon, which has **warmed and dried the
>   tropics**. These conditions not only limit the ability of forests to
>   draw down CO2 from the atmosphere but also trigger huge fires around
>   the globe that inject extra carbon into the air.
>
> [...]**The scientists used a seasonal climate model to predict sea-surface
>   temperatures in the Eastern Pacific - where the El Niño shows itself
>   most obviously - and then linked these to a statistical relationship
>   with CO2** to generate a picture of what levels would probably look like
>   across the calendar year. This gives an average for 2016 of 404.45,
>   with a September low of 401.48 (again with errors of plus or minus
>   0.53ppm). The team has already had success in forecasting the 2016 high, recorded in May, of 407.7ppm. The group had predicted 407.57.
>   "It's important to note that this year's rise in CO2 is bigger than
>   the last El Niño, in 1997/8, because human emissions have gone up by
>   25% since then. So, it's the natural effect on top of the increasing
>   human effect," said Prof Betts.

Basically, the role of the tropical forest is fundamental in the [carbon cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_cycle). Plants remove carbon from the atmosphere through photosyntesis and store it in the biosphere.

El Niño causes a rise in the temperature of the eastern Pacific Ocean, thus causing a warming and drying of the tropical rainforest. This accelerates carbon decomposition and favors forest fires, decreasing the carbon-storing capacity of the tropical biosphere. The fires are particularly bad because they destroy the biosphere while at the same time producing high quantities of CO$_2$.

Comment: OK, so it sounds like a pretty *soft* explanation - decomposition, fires, and reduced uptake. I can't see the Nature article until I get to the library - are these somehow quantitatively ranked and addressed, like the number of excess tons of CO2 due to excess numbers of fires for example, or is it more like "it could be this, or this, or this, or some combination"? Thanks. Great answer I appreciate the time you put into it!

Comment: @uhoh Yes, a pretty soft explanation but nevertheless quite convincing for me :-) Right now I cannot access the Nature article either, so we will see when we read it! Thanks for your appreciation!

Comment: I just found that there is a link in this [BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-36521068) to the Nature paper that has permission to access the article on-line.

Answer (score 2):

The article and comment you refer to are not talking about physics. They are talking about the interpretation of CO2 etc measurements according to a *belief* in the model of "global warming is caused by CO2".

After retirement, I spent  two years researching the subject and looking into the programming assumptions. I entered interested and not doubting the premises and then, when going into the details of theory and programming I became convinced that the subject has little to do with physics, a lot to do with programming assumptions, and particularly with the belief that correlation means causation: i.e. little to do with the physics of the chaotic system that is weather and in long time climate.  I even gave lectures on this at my former institute. Then I got bored.

Even the plot that you are showing of CO2 rising shows little effect of El Nino on the rise.  CO2 affects temperature, but also higher temperatures in the oceans releases more CO2, so there is a correlation of the CO2 plot to temperature, partially seen also in the annual fluctuations around the average

[Here is the anomaly](http://data.giss.nasa.gov/gistemp/graphs_v3/) ( difference from a standard) of global temperature

[image: globalmonthl]

In 1998 there was a big el Nino, no strong effect on the curve of CO2 is seen.

The argument that the last time CO2 had reached 400ppm  in earth history the sea levels were 80 feet higher is spurious. If there were direct causation why are the seas so low now? One should keep in mind when reading warming literature : *correlation is not causation*.

> I'm not looking for individual opinions or theories, I'd like an explanation of the concepts presented in those two links, from a physics perspective.

The CO2 figure itself tells us that there is little  correlation between the 1998 el Nino and little correlation to the current one as the curve follows its extrapolation in rising. It just happened to reach 400ppm when the el Nino was strong. There is no physics presented in the links.

Comment: "In 1998 there was a big el Nino, no strong effect on the curve of CO2 is seen." But the effect is there; if you look at the minima in the annual cycle (in the first image posted, which runs from 1960-2015), the increase from 1998 minimum to 1999 minimum is bigger than usual.

Comment: @MitchellPorter yes, that is why I said "strong effect". The articles seem to say that the el Nino pushed the curve to 400, observationally correct ,  but a coincidence because the curve would go to 400 anyway a bit later, even if there had not been an el Nino.

Comment: The first article explains the causality - "scientists believe that emissions spiked due to a combination of warming and drying in the tropics, which can accelerate soil carbon decomposition, and large, drought-fueled fires". So that part of the annual carbon cycle gets a boost in a hot year, and it takes a few years for plant regrowth to compensate.

Comment: But I agree that this fluctuation of a few years' duration is not relevant to global warming. There it's the long-term upward trend which matters.

Comment: The seas are lower now because oceans and ice sheets have *really* long time-constants, so abrupt atmospheric temperature rises (a few hundred years, say) leads sea-level rise by perhaps thousands of years.  It is extremely trivial to see this is so.

Comment: @annav thanks for your time and thoughts. I don't think any one person can simply say objectively "nope, there is no physics here!" While these items may not *talk about* physics, a good physicist can often find some physics if they keep an open mind. I really appreciate your digging into the data, especially the previous events. It's driving me buggy that I can't see the article for another day or so, so your discussion is really setting the bar pretty high - I'll be reading more carefully and better informed. Thanks!

Comment: Of course there is physics in the system, but not described in the articles and  it is very very complex physics. Climate was the first example of dynamical chaos theory, and chaotic systems are notroriously not open to cause and effect hand wavings. http://www.lavoisier.com.au/articles/climate-policy/science-and-policy/chaos-theory-and-weather-prediction.pdf

Comment: @annav You are mixing up climate and weather (as is the document you reference).  Weather is indeed chaotic.  Climate generally is not, or not recently and not on short timescales (less than thousands of years).  If climate was chaotic things like agriculture would be impossible and we would therefore not be here to worry about it.

Comment: @tfb please see this definiton by the IPCC itself  :"Chaos A dynamical system such as the climate system, governed by nonlinear deterministic equations (see Nonlinearity), may exhibit erratic or chaotic behaviour in the sense that very small changes in the initial state of the system in time lead to large and apparently unpredictable changes in its temporal evolution. Such chaotic behaviour may limit the predictability of nonlinear dynamical systems"  https://www.ipcc.ch/publications_and_data/ar4/wg1/en/annex1sglossary-a-d.html

Comment: @annav the key word there is 'may' and, as I said, weather does, climate does not (seem to): I can make really fairly good predictions of long-run temperature averages while I would be lucky to be able to predict the temperature in two weeks' time to within 5K.  I should perhaps mention that I work in a climate modelling centre.

Comment: @tfb  well I agree ,  it will depend on time scales and variables   but there does exist dynamical chaos for climate too.